# Can a specific class object fulfil a Protocol?

Tags: python, python-typing

Consider a `typing.Protocol` that requires the a simple method `foo() -> int`. Can class objects fulfil this protocol by defining `@classmethod`s?

```
class Proto(Protocol):
    def foo(self) -> int:
        ...
        
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls) -> int:
        return 23
    
foo: Proto = Foo
print (foo.foo())
```

Now the call works, but `mypy` complains:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Type[Foo]", variable has type "Proto")
```

Is there any way around that?

mypy 0.910
Python 3.9.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an [open issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4536) in mypy. Guido van Rossum agrees that this should work, but mypy does not accept it.